# iPhone / iPad Table View Reload Only One Row Instead Of The Entire Table

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, reloaddata

Instead of a

```
[table reloadData]
```

Is there a way to tell the table to reload just one row?  There are reasons for my madness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:). The method is called `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. So you'd do something like:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:2],
                       // Add some more index paths if you want here
                       nil];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:

```
(void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths 
          withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnnimation *)annimationStyle
```